# SpriteKit SKPhysicsBody inside another SKPhysicsBody

Tags: objective-c, collision-detection, physics, skphysicsbody

I am trying to make something like wiggle eyes.
Like this one: http://www.nationalartcraft.com/images/sub-0283-01.jpg

At first - is it possible to put one object into another and let it bounce inside the outer
-object in SpriteKit?

For example - I have a ring which represents the outline of the eye. And a smaller circle that represents the pupil.

When I create a physicsBody `bodyWithCircleOfRadius` and then position the smaller circle also with a physicsBody inside the ring it falls/jumps out.

Hopefully there is any way to solve this problem =/

Comment: Yes, the outer collision ring must be a static "edge" based body. Dynamic bodies can't be inside one another.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any work around? Is it somehow possible to create wiggle eyes? Some fake or something like this?

Comment: That's the workaround. The outer collision needs to be an edge-based body. If you look in the reference, it starts with two ways of creating either "volume-based" (dynamic, ie the eye) and "edge-based" (static, ie immovable, impenetrable walls) bodies. In this case bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath: with a path defining the shape would be what you need to define the eye "walls", and then put your circle eye body inside.